# How to return to same tab I came from in tabLayout

Tags: android, tabs, floating-action-button, onbackpressed

I have 3 tabs in tabLayout. When you are currently using Tab 2 or 3 if you click on my FAB button and go to GROUPS class, when you click my custom "back" button in GROUPS class, you'll always only be returned to the 1st tab, not the 2nd or 3rd where you came from.

However, if in the GROUPS class you click on the android "back" button, it'll take you back to whichever tab you came from.

So my custom button code is:

```
    final Button BackToMainActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ToMainActivity);
    BackToMainActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent startIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(startIntent);

         overridePendingTransition( R.anim.animate_downfade, R.anim.animate_down);

        }

    });
```

Here's the "back" button provided by all Android devices:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animate_downfade, R.anim.animate_down);
  }
```

So how do I make my custom "back" button in GROUPS class, also return the user to the tab they came from just like Android's "back" button?

Answer (score 0):

In your on click event, simply just call finish()

It will return you to what ever activity you haven't closed.

and make sure you don't close the activity that hosts your fragments when you go to your groups class.

what you're doing is starting your MainActivity from 0 so it has no idea which tab you were in.

just start your groups activity without finishing your main so that main activity gets paused until you return to it.